# JQuery ajax call not rendering the html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an ajax call to the database server to get the image as a base64 encoded string, the server is returning the base64 encoded image correctly I did check this in firebug, I need to use this encoded string as an hyper reference of an anchor on a page.

here is my client code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx',
        data: { ID: imageId },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text/plain',
        success: onAjaxSuccess,
        error: onAjaxFail
    });

function onAjaxSuccess(result) {
    var anchor = document.getElementById('hlImage0');

    var base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,' + result;
    anchor.href = base64Image;
}
```

The problem here is the anchor element **hlImage0** is not setting the *href* property and nothing is rendered on the page from the onAjaxSuccess callback.

Answer (score 0):

Image balise have on href attribute !

Try changing `anchor.href` by `anchor.src` instead !

Comment: No luck with this. Actually its an anchor tag and anchor tags do have an href attribute, the same thing works in a simple js function but in the onAjaxSuccess function it doesn't work. Maybe because the onAjaxSuccess is an async function that requires something else to be done

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. Do you want a <a href> click goes to a image loaded by ajax ? Or display an image loaded by ajax ?

Comment: I just want to set the base64 encoded string which is actually an image to the href attribute so that a click on the anchor will load show an image.

Comment: Hum ok ... And what `anchor.href` contains after `anchor.href = base64Image;` ? Can you console.log(); or looking using browser debugger tools ?

Comment: well friend, the anchor.href doesn't actually get rendered i.e. no href property is set to an anchor when I view the page source after the onAjaxSucess call.

Comment: Have you tried different images ? Smaller (with less chars) ? If you replace image by classical http link, is it working normally ?

Comment: Yes it works when I set the same href attribute from any js function other than the onAjaxSuccess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26802/discussion-between-anaelfavre-and-jaunty)